# Números faltantes en un array

Tags: php, mysql, array

necesito mostrar los numeros faltantes en una tabla, entre los que ya están insertos.
Encontré el siguiente script en la web:

```
$testArray = array(1,2,3,5,9);
$arrayRange = range(1,max($testArray));
$missingValues = array_diff($arrayRange,$testArray);
print_r($missingValues);
```

Pero lo que no logro es colocar todos los valores de la tabla en la variable $testArray, haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes");
```

Alguna ayuda, por favor?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: No entiendo la relación entre el array y la query, que es lo que estás intentando hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez lo que necesitas es convertir el resultado de la consulta a un array

```
$testArray = array();
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $testArray [] = $res['id_cliente'];
}
$arrayRange = range(1,max($testArray));
$missingValues = array_diff($arrayRange,$testArray);
print_r($missingValues);
```

Comment: Perfecto! Es lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias!